# Simple closed curve in $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

A simple closed curve is a continuous function from [a b] to $\mathbb C$. Does a pair of concentric circles represent a simple closed curve? What about 3 concentric circles?

My thinking is that a pair of concentric circles is not the continuous image of a closed and bounded interval in $\mathbb R$. Since continuity fails it can not be a simple closed curve. Similarly any collection of n concentric circles. Can someone throw light on the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb C$ is continuous, then $f([a,b])$ is  connected, since $[a,b]$ is connected.

Any  collection of $n$ concentric circles is  not connected !

Conclusion ?

Comment: Conclusion is " not a simple closed curve. "